# SQL Calculate the age .use DatePart on DATE()) minus year of birth

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Find the star number, name, date of birth, and current age of all stars who were born before January 1, 1925 and who are still living.  Calculate the age based on the current year (use DatePart on DATE()) minus year of birth.

Current Query :

```
SELECT StarNum, FirstName,LastName,StarBorn,StarDied,Datepart("yyyy",StarBorn- date()) AS age
FROM Star
WHERE StarBorn < #01/01/1925# AND StarDied IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Datepart` use `Datediff` to calculate `age`.

and the formula i used to calculate `age` is

```
DATEDIFF("h",DOB,date())/8766
```

Try this.

```
SELECT StarNum, FirstName,LastName,StarBorn,
       StarDied,DATEDIFF("h",StarBorn,date())/8766  AS age
FROM Star
WHERE StarBorn < #01/01/1925# AND StarDied IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a more accurate age of a person. I believe this is specific to the day of birth.

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```